# "Dynamic cast failure failure" from AnyObject? to Int

Tags: casting, swift, option-type

Nutshell - I'm trying to get a highscore out of a plist

Here's the code to read the data:

```
    var myOutput: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore")
    println(myOutput!)
```

This is successful and the result of the println is the correct data

```
    if myOutput != nil{
        highscore = myOutput! as Int
    }
```

This gives me a "Swift dynamic cast failure". From everything I've read this should be working, so any tips would be great.

Comment: can you change AnyObject to int or NSInteger - does the issue still occur?

Comment: nope. and I tried adding "as Int" in the original var myOutput definition, but that failed too

Comment: This means that the value of `myOutput[!]` is *not* an Int. What *is* it? An NSString, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user2864740 got me on the right track. Correct solution is:

```
    if myOutput != nil{
        highscore = myOutput!.integerValue
    }
```

Comment: Or with an "conditional assignment": `if let theOutput = myOutput { highscore = theOutput.integerValue }`

Comment: You can avoid the `String to Int` conversion using the specific methods provided by `NSUserDefaults`: `setInteger` to save the Int and `integerForKey` to load it. Please  note that the `integerForKey` returns an `Int` (not an `Int?`). So it returns an Int also if no value is found for the key you are passing as parameter, in this case 0 is returned.

Comment: @appzYourLife: But then you cannot distinguish between "no value set" and "value zero set".

Comment: @Martin R: Yes, exactly. That's why I highlighted the fact that integerForKey does not return an optional. Depending on the logic of the app/game it can make sense.

Comment: @Martin R: Anyway +1 to your comment for having underlined the concept and the potential disadvantage.